# CakePHP: Multiple relations to the same model with HABTM

Tags: cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 3 tables: users, estruturas and estruturas_users. 
Estruturas with this fields: id, name, user_id and hasAndBelongsToMany Users.

User model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Estrutura' => array(
            'className' => 'Estrutura',
            'joinTable' => 'estruturas_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'estrutura_id',
            'unique' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Estruturas model:

```
class Estrutura extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Estrutura';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );


    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'estruturas_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'estrutura_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'unique' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Estruturas controller:

```
function edit($id = null) {
    $this->layout = 'admin';
    if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid estrutura', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin'));
    }
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Estrutura->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The estrutura has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'admin'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The estrutura could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Estrutura->read(null, $id);
    }
    $users = $this->Estrutura->User->find('list');
    $anos = $this->Estrutura->Ano->find('list');
    $estruturatipos = $this->Estrutura->Estruturatipo->find('list');
    $ciclos = $this->Estrutura->Ciclo->find('list');
    $users = $this->Estrutura->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'anos', 'estruturatipos', 'ciclos', 'users'));
}
```

In my edit view I have this error:
Notice (8): Uninitialized string offset:  0 [CORE/cake/libs/view/helper.php, line 863] with:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
    echo $this->Form->input('nome');
    echo $this->Form->input('nome_completo');
    echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('ano_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('estruturatipo_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('ciclo_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('User'); //the error is here
?>
```

What I have wrong?
Thanks

Comment: The first problem I see is that you use two relationships with the same name.You don't need to use the name of the other model in the relatioship you linkwith the attribute className.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the User field in your database. Maybe what you are looking for is to remove echo `$this->Form->input('User');` and move it to the top of your form like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the var $ belongsTo. I changed User to User1 and verify that the error is in the model. In my user.php I have virtual fields and the problem is with it. I have to change to:

```
function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    $this->virtualFields['nomeUser'] = sprintf('CONCAT(%s.nome, " ", %s.apelido)', $this->alias, $this->alias);
}

var $displayField = 'nomeUser';
```

With $this->alias the problem is solve.

Thanks!